# View all private video thumbnails sorted by Recording Date on one page?

Tags: youtube, thumbnail

Is there a user script or browser extension that can show all of my YouTube account's private video thumbnails sorted by Recording Date on one page?

I have bulk-uploaded too many and need help organizing them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/), which can be downloaded as a python library/utility **or** a standalone Windows executable, to:

- You can avoid actually downloading the videos with the `--skip-download` option
- get a list of all of all of your videos using `--mach-filter "uploader = 'Mike Smith'"`
- with the `--get-url` option get the download URL and the `--get-title` can get the titles
- get the thumbnails using `--write-thumbnail` or the URLs of the thumbnails with `--get-thumbnail`
- Get the description with the `--get-description`

A little bit of post processing the results of using all of the above options should let you generate your own summary web page. Of course I personally would use [python](http://www.python.org/) to do this but there are lots of possibilities.

*All of the above is free, gratis & Open Source, software.*